# How to wait for document to finish loading in javascript when i am inside an event that occurs before

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, load, document

I am using JQuery Address plugin for address.change event
the problem is that this event occurs before document is fully loaded ( in FireFox & safari )

how can I wait for it to load?

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // put your address.change event and function here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shorter way:

```
$(function() {
    // code here
});
```